# How to pass dynamic values to JSON with duplicate fields

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a usecase where i have to send REST request in bulk.

JSON File: emp.json

```
[
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India"
        }
    }
]
```

My shell script:

```
func emp_details
{
START=1
END=1000000
CURRENT=1
while [ $END -gt $CURRENT ];
do
CURRENT=$((CURRENT+1))
cat emp.json | jq --arg new "$CURRENT" '.[].field.empID |= $new' > temp.json
cat temp.json
curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d @temp.json
done
}
```

The above json and script is working. I am able send the request properly.
I am looking for an approach to prepare the json file with mutiple empID before triggering the CURL.

For Example:

```
[
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    }
]
```

But am not sure how to traverse through each individual empID field and replace its value with dynamic CURRENT values.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What is your expectation? You want to have `empID` from 1 to 1000000 as JSON objects ? an send them all in one JSON?

Comment: Yes , Correct. I am looking to pass the dynamic value from shell to JSON file.Or anyother approach to prepare the JSON file with empID in incremental value will also help

Comment: You want to create 1000000 objects starting with `empID` as 1 ?

Comment: No. I want to create 1000000 objects with empID value starting from 1 and ending with 1000000.

Comment: Are you sure your receiver program can handle 1 million objects?

Comment: Yes It can handle. It can handle upto 4 million also. I am not exactly looking for 1000000 value. I am looking for an approach to prepare the JSON file with more objects with same field name but value should be in incremental order. As described in the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `bash` processing at all for this. You can use the `range()` function in `jq` to create the number range from 1 to million and create multiple objects using the `reduce()` function

```
jq -n 'reduce range(1; 1000000) as $data (.; . + [{"field": { "empID": $data, "location": "India"}}])'
```

This creates a million objects inside the array with `empID` set, starting from 1. Modify the value inside `range()` to customize the numbers.

Comment: `jq -n 'reduce range(1; 1000000) as $data (.; . + [{"field": { "empID": $data, "location": "India"}}])' | wc -c` → `78888819` This produces a 76M JSON. With `-cn`: → `45888851` 44M. Can save more by sending a compressed data: `jq -cn… | gzip | curl --data-binary -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -X POST https://api.example.com/submit` → `2556262` bytes or 2.5M. Probably worth it.

Comment: Works perfectly. This is the solution I was looking. Thank you

Comment: @LéaGris: Thanks for the comment. Will let OP tune how he wants to sent the record. Because I heard they might not be sending the whole 1 million records

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `range` built-in.

```
.[] | [.field.empID = range(1;1000000)]
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/6Gss5N6Fxu)</sup>