# Partition JSON data using jq and then send Rest query

Tags: rest, shell, jq, partition

I have a json file like below

```
[
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    }
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    }
        {
        "field": {
            "empID": "sapid",
            "location": "India",            
        }
    }
    .... upto 1 million
]
```

I have to use this json as an input for a rest request For example

```
curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d @temp.json
```

My server will not accept 1 million json object at a time.
I am looking for an approach where i have to extract the first 500 objects from the main json and send it in one rest query and then next 500 object in second rest query and so on.

Can you please suggest how can i achieve this by jq?

Comment: You had asked this question before and the response was in one of the comments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653907/how-to-pass-dynamic-values-to-json-with-duplicate-fields#comment109059664_61654926. It involves sending the application content as binary, instead of JSON

Comment: Please fix the sample JSON, in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Please also be explicit as to whether or not the REST server requires each request to contain exactly one valid JSON entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an intrinsic tradeoff here between space and time efficiency. In the following, the focus is on the latter.

Assuming that each call to `curl` must send a JSON array, a time-efficient solution can be constructed along the following lines:

```
< array.json jq -c '
  def batch($n): length as $l | range(0;length;$n) as $i | .[$i: $i+n];
  batch(500)
' | while read -r json
do
    echo "$json" | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d -@ ....
done
```

Here `....` signifies additional appropriate curl arguments.

### GNU parallel

You might also want to consider using GNU [parallel](/questions/tagged/parallel), e.g.:

```
< array.json jq -c '
  def batch($n):
    length as $l
    | range(0;length;$n) as $i
    | .[$i: $i+n];
  batch(500)
' | parallel --pipe -N1 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d @- ....
```

Comment: The OP mentions `"Content-Type: application/json"`, which suggests the data being sent by curl must be valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @peak. This approach helped in achieving the expected result

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared any HW information of the system you are running this on. At the minimum you need to do some sort of multiprocessing to make this faster instead of running (1000000/500) curl requests altogether.

One way, would be to use GNU `xargs` which has a built-in to run number of parallel instances of a given process using the `-P` flag and number of lines of input to read from at any time with the `L` flag.

To start with you can do something like below to instruct curl to run on 500 lines at a time and invoke 20 such invocations in parallel. So at a given tick, approximately (500 *20) lines of input are processed. You can tune the numbers depending on your HW capability both on the host and the server side.

```
xargs -L 500 -P 20 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://sample-url -d @- < <(jq -c 'range(0;length;500) as $i | .[$i: $i+500]' json)
```

Modified `jq` filter to pack the JSON payload as an array of objects (credit [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63482061/5291015)). The earlier version `jq -c '.[]' json` might not work as the individual chunk of lines passed at a time doesn't represent a valid JSON.

Note: Not tested due to performance constraints.

Comment: Thanks @Inian! for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this formatting, splitting can be done by unpacking the array and saving the desired number of objects to separate files, e.g.:

```
<input.json jq -c '.[]' | split -l500
```

Which creates `xaa` with the first 500 objects, `xab` with the next 500 objects, etc. If you want to repackage the objects in an array, use the `-s` option to `jq`, e.g.: `jq -s . xaa`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this from the shell, you could use `jq` to split your JSON and pass it to `xargs` to call `curl` for each object returned.

```
jq -c '.[]' temp.json | xargs -I {} curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

This will send *one* `curl` request for each object. However, if you e.g. want to send the first 500 objects in *a single* `curl` request, you can specify a subarray in the `jq` filter. To send all of your JSON objects you will then somehow need to repeat the command, as afaik `jq` has no built-in way to split the input into chunks of objects.

```
jq -c '.[0:500]' temp.json | xargs -I {} curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
jq -c '.[500:1000]' temp.json | xargs -I {} curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
jq -c '.[1000:1500]' temp.json | xargs -I {} curl <REST Server URL with temp.json as input> "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
[...]
```

Comment: You would need 1000000/500 invocations of `jq` with `xargs` and curl. Do you beleive this is optimal?

Comment: @Inian: No, it surely is not optimal. However, I assumed that the REST API would not accept a series of JSON objects in the payload but would need them to be packaged in one array. I could not think of a way of doing this without 1000000/500 invocations of `jq` (or some other command). Re-reading the question, I now see that there is no such specification.